# How to specify a starting number for numbered section headings in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I'm generating a Word document using Quarto, under R environment, and I want to specify the starting number of numbered headings. When we indicate `number-sections: true` the default number for the first heading is 1. Is it possible to indicate a custom start number?

Here is a simple code example.

```
---
title: "My Document"
format:
  docx:
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 3
    highlight-style: github
---

# Presentation

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et voluptate consequuntur vel ullam illum et omnis facilis.

# Development

Sed labore quisquam ea nihil nostrum sed quia praesentium et accusantium dolor non quia iste aut deserunt quibusdam.

# Fancy Results

Aut soluta fugiat est autem deserunt vel quam consectetur rem cumque officiis ad expedita delectus ut fugiat fuga.
```

This code generates the following text:

[image]

How to make the numbering of headings start, for example, at **3**?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code?

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer and leave it here

To star at 3 include `number-offset: 2`

```
---
title: "My Document"
format:
  docx:
    number-sections: true
    number-offset: 2
    number-depth: 3
    highlight-style: github
---
```